# WebDriver:Java - How to get all invsible buttons on webpage and click any one button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a web application which have the div structure as given below

```
<div class="hover-buttons">
  <a id="j_idt59:0:j_idt62" href="javascript:void(0);" class="  btn btn-padding-side" ng-click="click($event,{s:&quot;j_idt59:0:j_idt62&quot;,p:&quot;j_idt56&quot;});">
    <i class="icon left "></i>
    Transfer
  </a>
  <a id="j_idt59:0:j_idt64" href="javascript:void(0);" class="  btn btn-padding-side gray-dark" ng-click="click($event,{s:&quot;j_idt59:0:j_idt64&quot;,p:&quot;j_idt56&quot;,u:&quot;breadcrumb mainPage accAddServicesPanel&quot;});">
    <i class="icon left "></i>
    Account Details
    <div scrolltopfunction=""></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I need to get all the buttons on the page with tag `<a id>` and click on any one button which have dynamic IDs changing.

The number of buttons displayed on page varies everytime logged In and these are invisible by default. Kindly advice on how to get all buttons and click any one button.

Comment: I have tried this.. but the below logic clicks on the first button present                                                                `List<WebElement>mylist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_idt59']"));
     for(WebElement ele:mylist) {
      
      ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'j_idt64')]"));
     
      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
      js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);`

Comment: You just check `isDisplayed()` condition and check on visible button as `List<WebElement>mylist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='j_idt59']")); for(WebElement ele:mylist) { if(ele.isDisplayed()) { ele.click(); }} `

Comment: That will click the first element. What If Wanna click the one last in the list? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want random click??

Comment: Yes. random click

Comment: Then try provided answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want random click from the list of `WebElement` try using [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) as below :-

```
import java.util.Random;

Random random = new Random();

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.id("j_idt59"));
list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())).click();
```

**Edited** :- If want to click with certain condition instead of random click try as below :-

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'j_idt59')]"));

for(WebElement el : list){
     if(el.getAttribute("id").contains("j_idt64")){
            button.click();
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: This worked thanks. :) one more thing I want to check, what If I need to iterate the loop and click next button instead of random ?

Comment: with which condition do you want to click on next button??

Comment: In the same condition, instead of random, I want to click 2nd or 3rd button.

Comment: I have put it in this way `Random random = new Random();

     List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'j_idt64')]"));
     list.get(random.nextInt(list.size())).click();`      but the buttons have id `j_idt59:0:j_idt64` , `j_idt59:1:j_idt64` soforth. so want to click particular button

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand..why are using random then if you want to click on particular button. I have provided it in edited answer..

Comment: I was been asked to explore options as part of my project POC so looking at all options. Thanks

Comment: @Aditya But at the time you can click only one option, it is impossible to click one by one at the same time due to stale of element

Comment: I think random click is better way to exploring all options

Comment: I understand your point, and I aware that only one element can be clicked at a time. :)

Comment: Got it.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Get all links
2. Iterate over links & compare for link text you required

Here's the code snippet I think may help you:

```
        List<WebElement> listOfButtons = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.hover-buttons > a"));

        for(WebElement button : listOfButtons){
            if(button.getText().trim().equals("Your Button text")){
                button.click();
            }
        }
```